# Converting date in netcdf file in r was problematic

Tags: r, netcdf

I have to convert the numerical dates in `NetCDF` file to `date` object in `r`. Please see the attribute below.

```
        time  Size:341880
            grads_dim: t
            grads_mapping: linear
            grads_size: 341880
            grads_min: 01z01jan1980
            grads_step: 60mn
            units: days since 1-1-1 00:00:0.0
            long_name: time
            minimum: 01z01jan1980
            maximum: 00z01jan2019
            resolution: 0.0416666679084301
```

The code I used for converting is below. The resulted `date` object just does not start from Jan 01, 1980, as indicated in the attribute table.`dput` reproducible is also available below. Any ideas here?

```
time_rt <- convertDateNcdf2R(time, units = "days", origin = as.POSIXct("1-1-1 00:00:0.0",tz = "UTC"),
                             time.format = c("%Y-%m-%d", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", 
                                             "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", "%Y-%m-%d %Z %H:%M", "%Y-%m-%d %Z %H:%M:%S"))

> head(time_rt)
[1] "1980-01-13 01:00:00 UTC" "1980-01-13 02:00:00 UTC" "1980-01-13 03:00:00 UTC" "1980-01-13 04:00:00 UTC" "1980-01-13 05:00:00 UTC" "1980-01-13 06:00:00 UTC"

> dput(time[1:20])
structure(c(722816.041666667, 722816.083333333, 722816.125, 722816.166666667, 
722816.208333333, 722816.25, 722816.291666667, 722816.333333333, 
722816.375, 722816.416666667, 722816.458333333, 722816.5, 722816.541666667, 
722816.583333333, 722816.625, 722816.666666667, 722816.708333333, 
722816.75, 722816.791666667, 722816.833333333), .Dim = 20L)
```

Comment: I don't think there was a UTC timezone in the year 1 of the "Common Era".

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem by using the package `RNetCDF`. Try the code below.

```
utcal.nc('days since 1-1-1 00:00:0.0', time_raw, type = 's')
```

Comment: This appears to set some sort of base date, perhaps: 1901-01-01 or 2001-01-01 or perhaps the putative birthday of Jesus of Nazareth? The help page for `utcal.nc` uses unambiguous dates. Since you didn't actually say what your goal was in the question, it's difficult to know if this is the correct answer.